# Null-homotopic in terms of mapping cone

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a chain map, i.e. $A,B$ are chain complexes. The mapping cone of $f$, denoted by $C(f)$, is the chain complex with $C(f)_n=A_{n-1}\oplus B_n$ and differential $D(a,b)=(-da,db-f(a)).$

I want to develop a criterion for $f$ being null-homotopic, i.e. $f$ beging  chain-homotopic to the zero (chain-)map in terms of $C(f)$.

I started to show that $C(f)$ is indeed a chain complex. That is done now. But for the main part, I don't get along well.

Comment: There is a criterion in terms of the cone $C(id_A)=CA$; A chain map $f:A\to B$ is null homotopic if and only if it extends to a map on the cone $\bar{f}:CA\to B$. I can elaborate on this if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, that would be great. What do you mean with "extends" here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f:A\to B$ be a chain map. Then, applying the cone construction you have above to the identity chain map $id_A:A\to A$ gives a complex $CA = C(id_A)$ with $CA_n = A_{n-1}\oplus A_n$ and differentials
$$d:CA_n\to CA_{n-1},\quad d(x,y) = (-dx,dy-x).$$
What I meant by an extension in the comment above is that there exists a chain map $\bar{f}:CA\to B$ such that
$$\bar{f_n}(0,x) = f_n(x),\quad \forall x\in A_n.$$
We then have the following result:

> A chain map $f:A\to B$ is null-homotopic if and only if there exists an extension $\bar{f}:CA\to B$ of $f$ to the cone $CA$.

For the direction $(\Rightarrow)$, if $f$ is null-homotopic, there exists a sequence of maps
$$\{s_n:A_n\to B_{n+1}\}$$
such that $f_n = d_{n+1}^B\circ s_n+s_{n-1}\circ d_n^A$ for all $n$. Then, we define an extension $\bar{f}:CA\to B$ by:
$$\bar{f_n}:CA_n\to B_n,\quad \bar{f_n}(x,y) = f_n(y)-s_{n-1}(x).$$
Showing that this is a chain map is elementary, so I'll leave it as an exercise.

For the direction $(\Leftarrow)$, you can use the condition that $\bar{f}$ is a chain map to build chain homotopies:
$$s_{n-1}:A_{n-1}\to B_n,\quad s_{n-1}(a) = -\bar{f_n}(a,0).$$
There's nothing fancy needed to show this gives a chain homotopy, so I'll leave this as an exercise as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You mean $\bar{f}_n(0,x)$ instead of $\bar{f}(x,0)$, don't you?

Comment: @user372565 Happy to help! And yes you are exactly right, I've edited a couple typos.

Comment: In the last expression, would you happen to mean to say $- \bar{f}_n(a, 0)$ instead? Otherwise the chain homotopy doesn't work. I would have proposed an edit, but SE requires at least 6 characters for an edit :P

Comment: @Elliot Yu Yes, I think you're right, since $a$ should be in $A_{n-1}$ and not $A_n$. Thanks for letting me know!